# regex for replacing alt tag with image source name

Tags: html, regex

I have been working with regex attempting to change 1000 files and both add image alt tag as the image name.

Example text to search / replace

```
<img src="path/someimagename.jpg" height="100" width="100" />
```

End state

```
<img src="path/someimagename.jpg" alt="someimagename" height="100" width="100" />
```

I am able to find items with out alt

```
(<img(?!.*?alt=(['"]).*?\2)[^>]*)(>)
```

replace:  `$1 alt="" $3`

and I'm able to find image name

```
<img\b[^<>]*?src=['"].*?\/([^.\/<>]*)\.[^.\/<>]*['"][^><]*?\>
```

I have not figured out to combine both and achieve the goal

Looking to use a text editor to replace all files.

Any suggestions or help would be great.

Comment: what you need replace alt="" to what? what should be in place of alt?

Comment: You could add a small script to all your pages that does that. `$("img").each(function() { $(this).attr("alt", $(this).attr("src")) } )`.

Comment: There is no regex functionality in HTML, so I'm assuming you're happy to have answers in JavaScript? Or is this to be done server side, php or other server side language?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create some capture group in your regular expression. I've slightly adapted your expression (it also supports now nested paths):

```
(<img\b[^<>]*?src=['"].*?\/?.*?)([^.\/<>]*)(\.[^.\/<>]*?['"])([^><]*?\>)
```

And then, you can replace it with this:

```
$1$2$3 alt="$2"$4
```

*You can see it [here (1)](https://regex101.com/r/ebow6o/1) in action.*

---

To also block all entries containing `alt=""` you can use the following regular expression:

```
(<img\b(?!.*alt=["'].*)[^<>]*?src=['"].*?\/?.*?)([^.\/<>]*)(\.[^.\/<>]*?['"])((?!.*alt=["'].*)[^><]*?\>)
```

*You can see it [here (2)](https://regex101.com/r/ebow6o/4) in action.*